# Angular Material 2 DataSource filter with nested object

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have angular 4 project with material 2, I want to filter the data in MatTable. DataSource filter is working fine when we filter data on field which are not nested.

```
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource([
     { orderNumber: 1, orderInfo: { type: 'ABC'}, date: '12/3/2012 9:42:39 AM'},
     { orderNumber: 3, orderInfo: { type: 'Hello' }, date: '12/2/2018 9:42:39 AM'},
]);
```

Filter is working fine for orderNumber, date but not working properly with type field in orderInfo object.

Comment: Please post the filter logic.

Comment: applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
        filterValue = filterValue.trim();
        filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase();
        this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
    }

Answer (score 24, accepted):

DataSource has `filterPredicate()` method that needs to override in our application as follows. Add this code in your component after data source initialization.

```js
this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data, filter: string)  => {
  const accumulator = (currentTerm, key) => {
    return key === 'orderInfo' ? currentTerm + data.orderInfo.type : currentTerm + data[key];
  };
  const dataStr = Object.keys(data).reduce(accumulator, '').toLowerCase();
  // Transform the filter by converting it to lowercase and removing whitespace.
  const transformedFilter = filter.trim().toLowerCase();
  return dataStr.indexOf(transformedFilter) !== -1;
};
```

Comment: Add it in before:-
            this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
            this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
or anywhere in your ngOnInit() method after your this.dataSource initialization.

Comment: Is there still no smarter way for Angular 6? Sorting is also not working and if we have multiple columns it is very ugly to add this predicate x times...

Comment: @badera check out my posted answer for a solution to your problem

Comment: @badera Unfortunately, it still does not work today. Quite absurd how it still does not iterate through inner nested objects.

Comment: @badera for filtering just use the accepted answer. For sorting however, you can use material Table's sortDataAccessor,i.e. Just use this code after your filterPredicate.

this.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor = (item, property) => {
    switch(property) {
      case 'columnHeaderName': return item.orderInfo.type;
//define other cases for remaining column headers
      default: return "";
    }
  };

Answer (score 32):

Here is a solution that incorporates recursion so you don't have to hard code each nested object or their key/value pairs.

```js
this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data, filter: string)  => {
  const accumulator = (currentTerm, key) => {
    return this.nestedFilterCheck(currentTerm, data, key);
  };
  const dataStr = Object.keys(data).reduce(accumulator, '').toLowerCase();
  // Transform the filter by converting it to lowercase and removing whitespace.
  const transformedFilter = filter.trim().toLowerCase();
  return dataStr.indexOf(transformedFilter) !== -1;
};
```

And the `nestedFilterCheck`

```js
nestedFilterCheck(search, data, key) {
  if (typeof data[key] === 'object') {
    for (const k in data[key]) {
      if (data[key][k] !== null) {
        search = this.nestedFilterCheck(search, data[key], k);
      }
    }
  } else {
    search += data[key];
  }
  return search;
}
```

Thanks to [@Sagar Kharche](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3632602/sagar-kharche) for the `filterPredicate` override.

Comment: What should my markup look like when I add this filterPredicate? I currently filter on event (as per material documentation) like this: <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)"  but this throws an error: "Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined"

Comment: @RinandLen You would want `<input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">` and then in your code something like this `applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    filterValue = filterValue.trim(); // Remove whitespace
    filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase(); // Datasource defaults to lowercase matches
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
  }`

Comment: This method matches characters anywhere within the string. for ex using the search term "150" will match a record like "143157".  Is there any way we can limit records to ones that begin with the search term of "150"?

Answer (score 29):

This is a very generic solution and will work for sure. It does not depends on the structure of json, be it simple or nested, this solution works for all.

`this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data: any, filter) => {
    const dataStr =JSON.stringify(data).toLowerCase();
    return dataStr.indexOf(filter) != -1; 
  }`

Comment: Pretty smart solution, however this searches _property names_ too.

Comment: Simple and elegant ! well answered !

Comment: This works great! But how can you remove the problem @JeffreyRoosendaal presents? (About this searching for property names).

Comment: This does not work if you have multiple numeric or boolean values, only with strings. Otherwise have a `true` or the exact numeric value in another field will get the item filtered through, even if the exact property does not have the required value.

Comment: however this searches property names too. – Jeffrey Roosendaal
For this try to append the dataStr to only thode values which you want to make as searchable.

Eg. - {"name":"Chandan"}
const dataStr = JSON.stringify(data.name)

We can have loops for data array which obvious.

Comment: Great answer especially with @ChandanKumar 's last comment.